# Remote communication with R – How to start with an R GUI client to access R on a remote Server

Tags: r, qt, remote-access

I tried [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html)'s Qt example qdensity and really liked it. It was easy to setup and I was surprised how easy it was to understand and modify given that I have virtually no Qt experience. Now I wonder whether it is possible to use RInside with R somewhere on a remote machine.

It seems that I cannot use RInside for this purpose. I wonder whether there is another way of creating a Qt Desktop app, that communicates with R on some server. I got R Studio Server running and I am really happy with it, but it's for the R people. In order to promote my R stuff within our institute also among non-R people I would like to offer a simple, very limited GUI that can do basics things like showin' some graph or starting a `R CMD Batch`. I also know shiny (and shiny server) and have been actively testing it recently, but I am looking for a simple Desktop client go connect with my server-side R.

Is there a basis to start out with Rserve and Qt?
Any suggestions (where to start, examples, generally bad idea) ???

[What are R's capabilities to handle something like this IPC or D-Bus stuff](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/ipc.html).

Comment: Perhaps use http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/ ?

Comment: I do continue to test shiny, also installed shiny server and yes I love it. But testing it has shown that it is not battle-proof yet. Though I do realize that I ain't coming up with nothing better – not even for my specific problem – I just don't want to sit on my behind wait for the RStudio folks to do it. But actually you are right, I need to find out how shiny / R Studio Server communicate with R.

Comment: Do you want the GUI to use R to draw the graphs, or use its own non-R API to draw the graphs with data supplied from the R Server?  If the latter then [RServe](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/index.html) may be what you need.

Comment: It's rather the former, graphs should by drawn by R. Basically like http://rweb.stat.ucla.edu/ggplot2/ but a little bit more basic and a as a Qt client.

Answer (score 1):

Use Qt with C++, and just process the files that you create with R on you're server. 
So for example: create the graphic and save in a format that you can load. BMP, PNG etc. Load it to you're GUI.

Also I suggest Qt Creator for GUI design. Its fast and simple. This idea only fits you if you don't want to stay in in R environment.

Answer (score 0):

When I have created programs that process data and calculate things like probabilities and charts, usually use HTML for the interface using PHP and leaving the rest of the processing (for example R scripts) to the server.

Answer (score 0):

For any recent visitor: Take a look at [openCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/), it publishes R functions as restful services and does all the marshalling from R data types from and to JSON.